# replace very specific string instance in javascript (a parens and a comma)

Tags: javascript, regex

I looked through various posts but could not find a solution to my problem.

I have a query string that has elements that looks like

```
location IN ('Place A',  'Place B')
```

and sometimes I need to have it look like

```
location IN ('Place A', 'Place B') and person IN ('Security', 'HR')
```

I would like to be able to replace the " **),** " after Place B with " **) and** " so I can concatenate my query.  Sometimes I have several 'and' statements so this has to be (I guess) a global or '/g' switched replace statement.

I have tried

```
new_filter_string.replace(/[),]/g, ') and ');
```

but I get back a query that has removed parens and commas that should stay.  I am just looking to replace that very specific parens/comma string for ALL instances of it.

Thanks for your help with this, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
subject.replace(/\),$/g, ") and ");
```

---

**Regex Explanation**

> ),$

```
Match the character “),” literally «\),»
Assert position at the very end of the string «$»

) and

Insert the character string “) and ” literally «) and»
```

Comment: Hmm, tried this but it did not seem to work.  What is the '$' flag?

Comment: End of the line, you may try to remove it, I've tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `[),]` will match either an ending parenthesis or a comma. Remove the `[]` around them to match the sequence `),`, and escape the `)` as that is a special character in regular expressions:

```
new_filter_string.replace(/\),/g, ') and ')
```